# Bootstrap dropdown doesn't work with require bootstrap sass in Symfony 4

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, dropdown

I am encountering an issue with Bootstrap dropdown when requiring bootstrap sass in a JS file (`test.js`) :

```
require('bootstrap-sass');
```

Here is the template I wrote :

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block title %}{{ parent() }} | test{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }}
{% endblock %}

{% block body %}

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/js/test.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

And here is the Bootstrap dropdown which is part of the entire navbar in the parent template :

```
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Languages <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                <li><a href="#">Deutsch</a></li>
                <li><a href="/en">English</a></li>
                <li><a href="/fr">Français</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
```

The dropdown doesn't work with bootstrap sass and works well otherwise.
Thanks for help.

Comment: What are your `@import` statements, what is the code in `test.js`?

Comment: Maybe you need additional `@import`

Comment: There is only `require('bootstrap-sass');` for now..

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be that you are using `Bootstrap 3`.

You are requiring bootstrap 3 not 4! `Bootstrap-sass` references `Bootstrap 3` (https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/bootstrap-sass)

To require `Bootstrap 4` (as of time of writing currrent version is: v4.1.3) one have to run command `yarn add bootstrap`
(https://yarnpkg.com/en/package/bootstrap)